# Event binding for views in commonjs - BackboneJS

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I am currently working on BackboneJS and am kinda new to it.

I have this view called "product" which has the usual - product.tpl, product_app.js, product_controller.js and product_view.js. Apart from these I also have a commonJS.js, which as the name suggests contains data / functions common to all views.

I am currently binding events in the views using -
"eventname selector" : "functionname", in the events block of every view.

The issue is that there are some keypress/keydown events which I would like to bind in the commonJS so as to not write the same code over and over in all the views.

```
events:{
    "keydown .number-only": "isNumeric",
    "keydown .text-only": "isText",
    "keydown .alphanumeric": "isAlphanumeric"
},
```

Is there any way to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone accepts a method as the value of `events` property.

You can extend your common event data with the custom event hash for the view and return it:

```js
events: function() {
 // access commonEventHash from your common file
  return _.extend(commonEventHash, {
    "click .custom": "customMethod" // events specific to view
  });
}
```